# What is the correct way to define global variables between .py files

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have a Python project with multiple .py files. One file should be the "control" file, where parameters can be altered. Other files should receive input from this control file, and return varying outputs.

My code does as expected if I am using a fresh kernel (I am using Spyder in Anaconda), but after one run if I change a parameter in the control file, not all subsequent variables are updated.

I have searched stackoverflow and google but am struggling to find the "right way" to accomplish this. In the real case there are many more files with many more interdependencies, but I have boiled the problem down to the following simple example.

For example, control.py:

`var = 42`

file.py:

```
import control.py as con
var2 = con.var
print(var2)
```

Running file.py the first time prints `42`, as expected. But if within control.py I change to
    `var = 43`,
 save, and then run file.py again, I receive
     `42`

I want file.py to give `43` in this instance.

Comment: `global` variables are never a good idea. So i suggest you don't do that :)

Comment: All the import statement gets executed only at the start of system that is why it is not updating it to 43.
You can use some data storage thing to get and update these values. 
eg: redis, memcache
or you can store them in some dict (changes will be lost in dict when you restart the system)

Comment: This shouldn't be happening because if you modify and save `control.py` and then rerun `file.py` it should have the new value. There must be something else going on which accounts for the behavior. BTW, if `import control.py as con` isn't giving you an error, `control` must actually be a package, not a module (so no `control.py`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module is already imported, the change is not detected when you run the code again.

To force python to reimport, you may use the following function:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(con)

# After that
var2 = con.var
print(var2)
```